# Couldn't resolve the package 'firebase_messaging' in 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'

Tags: windows

Couldn't resolve the package 'firebase_messaging' in 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'.

How con i resolve this problem Couldn't resolve the package 'firebase_messaging' in 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart'.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.